# Mysql does not insert into table - flask

Tags: python, mysql, flask

I have a flask route that adds new customers via MySQL row queries. I expect the below function does insert to the table customer, but it seems it does not. Any help?

```
@app.route("/add", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def add_customer():
    """create new customer"""
    if request.method == "POST":
        sql = f"INSERT INTO customer(id,name) VALUES({request.form['id']},'{request.form['name']}')"
        cursor.execute(sql)
        db_conn.commit()
        flash("New customer created!")
        return redirect(url_for("home"))
    else:
        return render_template("addcustomer.html")
```

And here's *addcustomer.html* template/form

```
<!doctype html>
<title>Add customer</title>
<form action={{url_for('add_customer')}} method="POST">
    <p>Name:</p>
    <input type="text" size="50" name="name">
    <p>ID number:</p>
    <input type="number" size="50" name="id">
    <input type="submit" value ="Create">
    <a href = "{{url_for('home')}}"><button type="button">Cancel</button></a>
</form>
```

Comment: Can you post the [partial] `CREATE TABLE` statement for `customer`?

Comment: Are you sure you are sending a POST request? The code you show would not do an INSERT during a GET request.

Comment: @Marat
cursor.execute(
    """CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS customers(
            id INT PRIMARY KEY,
            name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL)"""
)

Comment: @BillKarwin Yes. I updated the question with the form.

Comment: The combination of `INSERT INTO` and passing an explicit primary key looks strange here. Can you try removing `id` from the query?

Answer (score 0):

Try request.form.get('field') instead of request.form['name']

```
@app.route("/add", methods=["GET", "POST"])

"""create new customer"""
if request.method == "POST":
    sql = f"INSERT INTO customer(id,name) VALUES({request.form.get('id')},'{request.form.get('name')}')"             
    cursor.execute(sql)
    db_conn.commit()
    flash("New customer created!")
    return redirect(url_for("home"))
else:
    return render_template("addcustomer.html")
```

Use request.form.get('name') and request.form.get('id') to get values and try to print it before executing the Query. also use %s instead of calling data into query (it will work but not a good practice).

you can fetch data from form using request.form.get('fieldname').